# vscode not reloading typescript in vue files

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code

I am working with Vue(SFC simple file component) and typescript using vscode. The types I am creating in a d.ts file are not applied/updated to .vue files. When I reload the window they get applied.
That means that I have to reload vscode every time I do change a d.ts file.

Someone knows how to solve it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try using this [plugin](https://github.com/prograhammer/vscode-tslint-vue).
Vscode got no Vue extensions by default.

Comment: Good point but still not working. I have to reload window to make typings work when I change them.

Comment: Have you tried this "Vetur" as well? 
Link: https://github.com/vuejs/vetur

Comment: Same problem here. I found out that including the `.vue` file type causes the `.d.ts` files not to be recognised anymore. I have filed an issue for it on the Vetur github, but they closed it - it's still not solved! https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/530